# Where can I find a complete description of JavaScript DOM class hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a more complete description of JavaScript's DOM class hierarchy than the one from JavaScript: The Definitive Guide? [image]

It doesn't show  many other classes such as `HTMLFormElement`, `HTMLButtonElement`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API doesn't seem to provide hierarchy information.

Comment: Unrelated: "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" is a pretty old and somewhat inaccurate book, it had its moment in the spotlight but I recommend looking at "Eloquent JavaScript" or the "Exploring JavaScript" series as two free alternatives that are more accurate. The 2ality books in particular are very well written! (full disclosure, I am a reviewer of one of the books but am in no way compensated for promoting them - I just genuinely like them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the DOM is described in the HTML specification, which is free, open source and available at http://html.spec.whatwg.org/

Note that this is declared in formal language (IDL) so that it is not ambiguous and browsers actually compile it into tests. For example here's [Document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#document). Here is for example [HTMLButtonElement](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlbuttonelement), [HTMLFormElement](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlformelement).

On top of that you have the WPT (web platform tests) that make sure that the non-formal parts are tested.

Comment: You didn't ask so I'm not making it part of the answer, but browsers contain their own copy of the IDLs for internal tests - so if you want to check for example what version of HTMLFormElement Chrome uses - you can check in their repo, here is Element for example: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/third_party/blink/renderer/core/dom/element.idl